# In java find the same salary in array

Tags: java

In java
I want to find the same salary.
I have two array

```
String[] employee = {“Doung”,”Chan”,”Minea”,”Mesa”,”Romdoul”,”Veha”,”Por”,”Kanika”};

int[] salary = { 560, 560, 500, 500, 190, 190, 560,700};
```

it mean that Doung has salary 560, Minea has salary 560, ....
I expect to get the result like this

```
Doung:560$
Chan:560$
Por:560$
Minea:500$
Mesa:500$
Romdoul:190$
Veha:190$
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far.

Comment: I want to find a salary that has more than two times.

Comment: When asking homework questions, please show your best good faith attempt to solve it and tell what problems you are having to give us a better understanding of your intentions, what you might be doing wrong, and your goal. Please go through the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help](http://stackoverflow.com/help), and the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/how-to-ask) sections to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions. Please also have a look at [How do I ask and answer Homework questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822)

Answer (score 0):

Here is complete example of your question.

Please check following code.

```
public static void main(String arg[]) {
        try {
            String[] employee = { "Doung", "Chan", "Minea", "Mesa", "Romdoul", "Veha", "Por", "Kanika" };
            int[] salary = { 560, 560, 500, 500, 190, 190, 560, 700 };
            int[] newSal = new int[salary.length - 1];
            String[] employeeSalary = new String[employee.length - 1];
            for (int i = 0; i < salary.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 1; j < salary.length; j++) {
                    if (salary[i] == salary[j] && i != j) {
                        newSal[i] = salary[i];
                        employeeSalary[i] = employee[i];
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            sortToArray(newSal, employeeSalary);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    static public void sortToArray(int[] salary, String[] names) {
        int temp;
        String sTemp;
        for (int i = 0; i <= salary.length - 1; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j <= salary.length - 2; j++) {
                if (salary[j] < salary[j + 1]) {
                    temp = salary[j];
                    salary[j] = salary[j + 1];
                    salary[j + 1] = temp;
                    sTemp = names[j];
                    names[j] = names[j + 1];
                    names[j + 1] = sTemp;
                }
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i <= salary.length - 1; i++) {
            System.out.println(names[i] + ":" + salary[i] + "$");
        }
    }
```

**Output :**

Doung:560$

Chan:560$

Por:560$

Minea:500$

Mesa:500$

Romdoul:190$

Veha:190$

Hope this solution works.

Please mark as answer if this is helpful to you.

Comment: Yes, I want it. Thank you

Comment: @LysaThorn please mark as answer if this solution helpful to you.